# Rewrite rule .htaccess for chinese characters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /somePage.php?parm=$1
```

Changes `example.com/example` to `example.com/somePage.php?parm=example`

With chinese characters (and I suppose any special chars) doesn't work.
How can I fix to any language?

Comment: http://dracos.co.uk/code/apache-rewrite-problem/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with any language , try this :

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$  /somePage.php?parm=$1
```

You could exclude whatever you want beside `.` in pattern so , if you want to exclude `+` change this `[^\.]` to this `[^\.+]` and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mohammed Elhag